# Do electromagnetic fields interact with air pressure?

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics

I would like to know whether electric and magnetic fields interact with air pressure. Do changes in magnitude or direction of such fields increase or decrease the air pressure in a given volume of air? Does it Does it affect the air flow? For example, could it change the flow from laminar to turbulent?

Comment: I genuinely don't see why there are close-votes on this question. It is asking a very specific, physically reasonable, conceptual question about physics.

Comment: Are you only interested in cases where EM fields affect air pressure, or are interactions in the opposite way (pressure affecting EM fields) also part of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, strictly speaking, there may be some extreme situations where, say, electric field could lead to pressure change. For example, if the electric field is high enough to initiate air breakdown (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown ), the air temperature and, therefore, air pressure can go up in the area of breakdown.

EDIT: As for your question about air flow... Again, if you have a discharge (breakdown), you can alter the air flow. You may look at http://www.spacedaily.com/news/future-00o.html or google "plasma aerodynamics". It looks like there is more data on microwave discharge affecting air flow than on DC discharge.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical generators produces electric fields inside gas cylinders in which magnet is placed inside. These magnet when kept in motion by motors, it makes the field of magnet and the fields of electricity to interact spontaneously. In doing so, there will be a change in voltage of electrical current(increase) thereby making the load to glow, increase in motion( particles collides  causing high pressure inside the cylinder) or particles collides causing a reduction of pressure inside the cylinder. When there is pressure deference,(atmospheric pressure and the pressure inside the cylinder, water flow from law level to high level through the gas Cylinders.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram illustrated the experiment how magnet interacts with fields to make a bulb glow. In the same way particles of atoms can expand making the gas inside the cylinder to be high than the atmospheric pressure. [image][image]